# cracklib-runtime in cron.daily is crashing Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, cron

I have found that **cracklib-runtime** crashes the OS when run by **cron.daily**. I have to physically reboot the computer.

Why does this happen and what are the implications of not having it in cron?

This is the content (system-default):

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

if [ -x /usr/sbin/update-cracklib -a -r /etc/cracklib/cracklib.conf ]
then
    status="$(/usr/sbin/update-cracklib)"
    if [ -n "${status}" ]
    then
        /usr/bin/logger -p cron.info -t cracklib "updated dictionary (read/written words: ${status})."
    else
        /usr/bin/logger -p cron.info -t cracklib "no dictionary update necessary."
    fi
fi

exit 0
```

Content of /etc/crackblib.conf:

```
# database (do not modify):
  readonly cracklib_dictpath="/var/cache/cracklib/cracklib_dict"


# database sources:
  cracklib_dictpath_src=""

  if [ -r "/usr/share/dict/cracklib" ]
  then
    cracklib_dictpath_src="${cracklib_dictpath_src} /usr/share/dict/cracklib"
  fi

  if [ -r "/usr/local/share/dict/cracklib" ]
  then
    cracklib_dictpath_src="${cracklib_dictpath_src} /usr/local/share/dict/cracklib"
  fi

  for i in /usr/share/dict /usr/dict /usr/local/share/dict /usr/local/dict
  do
    if [ -d $i ]
    then
      for file in $(find $i -type f -print | LC_ALL=C sort)
      do
        if $(file -z -b ${file} | grep -q "text")
        then
          cracklib_dictpath_src="${cracklib_dictpath_src} ${file}"
        fi
      done
    fi
  done
```